# how to add a Http header to all pages - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

How can I add a Http header to all of my pages? The website I'm working was developed using CakePhP and I would like to add the header below to all pages.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://url_of_my_website
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
In AppController.php
public function beforeRender()
{
    $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'your url');
}
```

Comment: In CakePHP 4 this is now `$this->response = $this->response->withHeader('X-CakePHP', 'yes!');`, because [the response object is immutable](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#common-mistakes-with-immutable-responses) therefore must be replaced.